# Message not showing on emulator screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

Here is the code to find the current location, but nothing shows on the screen after pressing the retreive button. 
I have reset adb and tried to send the data from emulator control manually. But when I send data using emulator control, then the emulator restarts but never shows the home screen.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
public class LbsGeocodingActivity extends Activity {

    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // in Meters

    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 1000; // in Milliseconds

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    protected Button retrieveLocationButton;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        retrieveLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieve_location_button);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
                MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                new MyLocationListener()

        );
    retrieveLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCurrentLocation();
            }
    });       

    }   

    protected void showCurrentLocation() {
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );
            Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }  

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String message = String.format(
                    "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                    location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
            );

            Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
            Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, "Provider status changed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,
                    "Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,
                    "Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code you might not be receiving the current location(this is because in you need to push your location manually through [emulator control](http://sree.cc/google/emulator-control-for-android-in-eclipse-ide)).

Just have else case also in showCurrentLocation() and check whether the location object is null or not like below.

```
protected void showCurrentLocation() {
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        String message = String.format(
                "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()
        );

    Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, message,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
       Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, "location is null",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right,it is showing "location is null" where is the probm then,gps is not working i think

Comment: on emulator gps wont work but you have emulator control where you can push your lat ans long manually for testing purpose

Comment: added link for emulator control

Comment: i have pushed the lat n lon using emulator control but its not working.i thought to use gpx. wil that work?

Comment: still showing "location is null" push data is long= -122.0841 lat= 37.44006  :(

Comment: is this becoz of a warning in AndroidManifest.xml ? the warning is "the hardcoded string"Retrieve Location" should use @string resource".

Answer (score 0):

On our first attempts to use the location sensors we had similar problems. Two things help the most in order to get the best results from GPS.

On the emulator the **`Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);`** causes a lot force closes.

And most important. Its far more stable to input the gps data through telnet. **`telnet localhost 5554`** (*You can see the port on the emulators window title*). The command for a new gps fix is: **`geo fix lat lng`**